# getting excerpt as substring in a wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I work on .NET applications but currently have to work on php/wordpress .I have a code in WordPress which displays title of a post on image mouse hover .

```
<h5><?php echo the_title(false, false); ?></h5>
```

I want to replace title with first line/sub string of Description of that post. 
OR 
I can use Excerpts here i.e to write some excerpts with each post and get them in above mentioned h5 tag. 
I require some hints in implementing any of two tasks. 
Note 
while performing my effort/testing purpose I wrote this code but its not working

```
<h5><?php echo substr(the_title(false, false),0,4); ?></h5>
```

Thanks ,

Comment: the_title() displays (echos) the title you need to use get_the_title()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use excerpt, try -

```
<h5><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h5>
```

Or a better approach will be to use **Custom fields**. You can easily add a Custom field with any post or page from the post/page edit screen. Use a specific key, ex: `subtitle`, the display that with get_post_meta function -

```
<h5><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'subtitle', true ); ?></h5>
```

Reference:
1. Function [the_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)
2. Function [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)
3. Function [get_the_ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)
4. How to add custom field [Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzkcmESTa0g)

Answer (score 0):

use function

```
<?php
$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
if ( $my_excerpt != '' ) {
   }
echo $my_excerpt; 
 ?>
```